# JSTL Foreach not working

Tags: jakarta-ee, jstl

i am new to Java EE. i am writing some code to print user list in jstl foreach. but it is not working. it is not printing any thing
here is my code

```
<%
            ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
            User user = new User();
            user.setUsername("usman");
            user.setPassword("123");
            list.add(user);
        %>
        <c:forEach items="${list}" var="user">
            <c:out value="${user.username}"></c:out>
            <c:out value="${user.password}"></c:out>
        </c:forEach>
```

please help me!

Comment: You are mixing Scirplet with JSTL. Either work completely using JSTL tags or use complete Scirplet(Not recommended). <C:foreach> is part of JSTL and <% %> is part of scriplet.

Comment: "please help me!" - Try not to sound so desperate ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always put business logic in middle layer (Can be a Servlet or a Service class). JSTL should just be used for presentation. So, in your case move following code to your Servlet and set result list into request attribute [As Alex said] -

```
ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
User user = new User();
user.setUsername("usman");
user.setPassword("123");
list.add(user);
request.setAttribute("list", list);
```

Now, you can access "list" in your JSP using JSTL as -

```
${list}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add into servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("list", list);
```

and you should not mix a code.